# IRC client does not print/receive full response

Tags: c, sockets, irc

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *host = "irc.libera.chat";
static char *port = "6667";
static char *chan = "#libera";
static char *nick = "nick";
static char *pass = NULL;

static int sock  = 0;

void
message(char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    /* determine size */
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int n = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (n < 0) {
        fputs("vsnprintf() failed", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t size = n + 1;
    /* construct */
    char *msg = malloc(size);
    if (msg == NULL) {
        perror("malloc() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = vsnprintf(msg, size, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (n < 0) {
        fputs("vsnprintf() failed\n", stderr);
        free(msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* send */
    ssize_t nsent = send(sock, msg, size, 0);
    free(msg);
    if (nsent == -1) {
        perror("send() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if ((size_t)nsent != size) {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "send() failed: expected to send %lu bytes, sent %ld instead\n",
                size, nsent);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int
main(void) {
    /* initialize connection */
    struct addrinfo hints = {
        .ai_flags     = 0,
        .ai_family    = AF_UNSPEC,
        .ai_socktype  = SOCK_STREAM,
        .ai_protocol  = 0,
        .ai_addrlen   = 0,
        .ai_addr      = NULL,
        .ai_canonname = NULL,
        .ai_next      = NULL
    };
    struct addrinfo *res;
    int ret = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    struct addrinfo *rp;
    for (rp = res; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sock = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sock == -1) {
            perror("socket() failed");
            continue;
        }
        if (connect(sock, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            perror("connect() failed");
            close(sock);
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(res);
    if (rp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not connect to %s:%s\n", host, port);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* log in */
    if (pass)
        message("PASS %s\n", pass);
    message("NICK %s\n", nick);
    message("USER %s - - :%s\n", nick, nick);
    /* join channel */
    if (chan != NULL)
        message("JOIN %s\n", chan);
    /* print response */
    char buffer[4096];
    ssize_t nbyte;
loop:
    nbyte = recv(sock, buffer, 4095, 0);
    if (nbyte < 0) {
        fputs("recv() failed", stderr);
        return 1;
    } else if (nbyte == 0) {
        fputs("recv() failed: connection closed prematurely", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    buffer[nbyte] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buffer);
    goto loop;
    /* unreachable */
}
```

outputs

```
:calcium.libera.chat NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:calcium.libera.chat NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:calcium.libera.chat NOTICE * :*** Couldn't look up your hostname
:calcium.libera.chat NOTICE * :*** No Ident response
ERROR :Closing Link: 127.0.0.1 (Connection timed out)
recv() failed: connection closed prematurely
```

- Why am I not receiving the proper response?

Other irc clients further output

```
:calcium.libera.chat 001 nick :Welcome to the Libera.Chat Internet Relay Chat Network nick
...
```

Could the issue be in error handling?

For example, according to `send(2)`

> On  success,  these calls return the number of bytes sent. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set to indicate the error.

so

```
} else if ((size_t)nsent != size) {
    fprintf(stderr,
            "send() failed: expected to send %lu bytes, sent %ld instead\n",
            size, nsent);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

seems redundant, as well as its `recv` counterpart.
Am I handling `vsnprintf` and `malloc` correctly?

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: `Checking Ident ... Looking up your hostname ... Couldn't look up your hostname ... No Ident response` - there is no IDENT server in your code.  Most IRC servers will connect back to the client's IP on port 113 and query its identity to prove the client is who it claims to be. So, you need to implement an IDENT server in your code, or at least have an IDENT server running in parallel to your client.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but it can't be the issue, because other irc clients give same four lines before outputting other, useful stuff as well.

Comment: Also, no, you are not handling `send()` correctly. If it returns > 0, but less then the number of requested bytes, you have to call `send()` again to finish sending the remaining unsent bytes. Having a return value that is not the same value as the requested size is not an error. The only error condition is a return value of -1. You need to call `send()` in a loop until all data has been sent.

Comment: `loop: ... goto loop;`?  Wow.  Haven't seen code like *THAT* for a few years ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are handling `vsnprintf()` and `malloc()` fine.  It is `send()` that you are not handling correctly.  There are two problems with your usage:

1. you are including the formatted string's null-terminator in the transmission.  Don't do that, that is not part of the IRC protocol.
2. you are not accounting for partial transmissions, as `send()` *can* return fewer bytes than requested, thus requiring `send()` to be called again to send any unsent bytes.  So you need to call `send()` in a loop.  A return value that is greater than 0 but less than the number of requested bytes is not an error condition. The only error condition is a return value that is less than 0.

Try this instead:

```c
void
message(char *fmt, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    /* determine size */
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    int n = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (n < 0) {
        fputs("vsnprintf() failed", stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_t size = n + 1;
    /* construct */
    char *msg = malloc(size);
    if (msg == NULL) {
        perror("malloc() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    n = vsnprintf(msg, size, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    if (n < 0) {
        fputs("vsnprintf() failed\n", stderr);
        free(msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /* send */
    char *curr = msg;
    --size; // don't sent null terminator!
    while (size > 0) {
        ssize_t nsent = send(sock, curr, size, 0);
        if (nsent < 0) {
            perror("send() failed");
            free(msg);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        curr += nsent;
        size -= nsent;
    }
    free(msg);
}
```

That said, you really shouldn't be using a `goto` loop in `main()`, either.  Use a `while` or `do..while` loop instead, eg:

```c
int
main(void) {
    ...
    /* print response */
    char buffer[4096];
    int exitCode = 0;

    do {
        ssize_t nbyte = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
        if (nbyte < 0) { 
            perror("recv() failed");
            exitCode = 1;
        } else if (nbyte == 0) {
            fputs("connection closed by peer", stderr);
            exitCode = 1;
        } else {
            printf("%.*s", nbyte, buffer);
        }
    }
    while (exitCode == 0);

    close(sock);
    return exitCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When you trace the application (E.g. using strace) you will see the following calls:

```
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(6667), sin_addr=inet_addr("172.106.11.86")}, 16) = 0
sendto(3, "NICK nick\n\0", 11, 0, NULL, 0) = 11
sendto(3, "USER nick - - :nick\n\0", 21, 0, NULL, 0) = 21
sendto(3, "JOIN #libera\n\0", 14, 0, NULL, 0) = 14
```

Meaning when sending the NICK, USER and JOIN, those strings are begin transmitted with an additional null byte at the end and the server on the other side doesn't like that.

This implies that in your code the `message()` method is wrong, more specifically the calculation of the `size` variable. If I compile your code with size decremented before the `send()` call, the connection to the irc server succeeds.

Comment: Woah, I would've never figured that out by myself. Btw, when I do `strace ./myprog` those sendtos look different, more convoluted